# Did not find suite classes in package Intellij IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, specs2

I have a poly repository kind project in Intellij IDEA built with Pants. Individual modules are built with sbt. So I want to debug Specs2 tests using Intellij IDEA debugger. I moved the module I need to debug into a separate sbt project in Intellij but each time I try to run Specs2 test suite from run/debug configuration I get an error: `Did not find suite classes in package`.
How can I mark my test classes as Specs2 suite in Intellij in order to debug my tests?

Here is how debug configuration looks like:
[image: run/debug config]

Also, I manually specified test directories and source directories accordingly in project settings:
[image: project seetings]

And I've set sbt build configurations to consider test classes:

[image: sbt build configuration]

Comment: Which Scala Plugin version are you using?

Comment: The version of the plugin is 2020.2.27

Comment: Did you place your tests under the `tests` folder (should be green)? Could you share a screenshot of your project view with the module with all folders expanded? Would be great if you created a ticket in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=SCL

Comment: I've updated my question with a screenshot. I can view in this window only on the directories/packages granularity

Comment: BTW it's enough to only mark single `scala` folder as tests root, without `tests` and `fs`

Comment: sbt-shell support is intended to work only when sbt is used as project main build system.

Comment: If you really want to debug your tests from IntelliJ you can create a "Remote" run configuration (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-remote-debug.html#67cb1), run sbt in terminal, add something like set `javaOptions in testOnly += "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=12345"` (maybe with `in Test` / `in run` / `in console`, don't remember exactly), and attach to it using "Remote" config